# For what period of time

Tags: questions

There is a mathematical model. Model can give a forecast for some duration (hours, days, years). But the forecast will not be equally accurate for different periods of time. How should I ask for what period of time the forecast is most accurate?

1. What is duration, the model can give most accurate forecast.
2. For whatduration....
3. What is duration for....

Which of the above is correct? Where can I read about this rule?

Comment: It seems like you're not very fluent in English grammar, so maybe our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) would be a better place for you.

Comment: *Which* **chooses between options,** which might be stated or implied. *What* asks for a specification. You actually use *what* in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I'll ask on ELL site. But I edited my question. I want to ask how to build the question.